# Griefed World Generator for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I find it fun trying to survive in a griefed environment in Minecraft, but it is tedious to create a new map, build lots of large buildings, half-tear them down, and then build thousands of tall towers out of random materials.  Is there a world generator that can create griefed maps like this automatically?

Comment: You might try googling "minecraft survival maps". That should get you quite a few premade maps of the type you want.

Comment: Almost certainly not. I'd advise you to set up a server, load it up with a [cool world](http://www.minecraftworldshare.com/) and invite in 4chan for an hour or so.

Comment: You're one of _those_ guys...

Comment: It's true. 4chan can ruin *anything*.

Comment: @QAdley Write out the instructions to automate doing that, and you have yourself a "griefed world"-generator. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no known map generator that will create a griefed style map. It's not impossible, but would require a very large effort to create the generator.

I would suggest going to the Minecraft forums and making a Request in the modding section. When you make your post, try to write out possible specifics for the generator.

- Style of buildings (Modern, Midevil, Asian, etc)
- Size of building (Width, Legnth, Height)
- Building material
- Style of grief (Random noise? General shape? etc.)
- Amount of grief (bits and pieces, whole chunks, etc)
- etc.

Hopefully a modder will come along who's interested in helping. Things can then move forward from there. If there's no response there, try over at the Bukkit forums.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps taking a lot of premade maps and let people come onto your server in perhaps using the Nodus IRC, I had setup a Griefing server and bunch of people came and of course, griefed it all! Was pretty fun and some people donated for WE.